# Vlookup with Pandas Merge between 2 files selecting 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I'm trying to make a simple python script using pandas for a Vlookup-like excel purpose.

I've 2 txt files tab-delimited (i.e. All.txt and Half.txt):

**All.txt:**

[image]

**HALF.txt:**

[image]

What I need is to fill the gaps ("N_Casos_LCR" and "Location_LCR" of All.tx file) of All.txt with the matching "Variant_ID".

So I set up (or I think I set) the index "Variant_ID" column from All.txt, but I get the next error.

Any help or suggestion is more than welcome!
thanks!

**Input code:**

```
import pandas as pd

falta=open('Half.txt','rb')
todo=open('All.txt','rb')

df1 = falta.readlines()
df2 = todo.readlines()

df2.set_index("Variant_ID",inplace=True)
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on="N_Casos_LCR", how='left')
df3.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                 
File "BuscarV2.py", line 9, in <module>                                                            
df2.set_index("Variant_ID",inplace=True)                                                     
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Comment: your issue is you're not creating dataframe objects, try `pd.read_csv(target_to_txt_file)`

Comment: df2 is not a data frame, convert that into data frame. then it should work.

Comment: I've tried with this: `df1=pd.read_csv("FullUniqVariants_LCR.txt",delimiter="\t")`

`df2=pd.read_csv("Comun-Tumor-LCR-Plasma.txt",delimiter="\t")` but it is not working